Which illusion spells would serve to conceal the entrance to a small cave on a long-term basis?
Introduction
I'm the GM for a Pathfinder-1e game in which an NPC wants to conceal the entrance to a small cave behind an illusion of natural stone on a long-term basis. I've looked at a few different options, but I'm not sure which ones will actually work.
An ideal answer would cite a published adventure in which one of these spells was used to accomplish something similar. A forum post or other clarification from a designer would also be helpful. Information about how these spells descriptions have changed since D&D 3.5 and earlier would also help, since it might help me infer the author's intent.
Considered Options
Illusory Wall
The cave entrance is small enough to be hidden by an illusory wall, which seems like an ideal solution if it actually works. However, from the description of illusory wall, I'm not totally sure that it does work (emphasis added):

Illusory Wall
School illusion (figment); Level sorcerer/wizard 4; Subdomain ambush
5; Mystery streets 4
CASTING
Casting Time 1 standard action Components V, S
EFFECT
Range close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels) Effect image 1 ft. by 10 ft. by
10 ft. Duration permanent Saving Throw Will disbelief (if interacted
with); Spell Resistance no
DESCRIPTION
This spell creates the illusion of a wall, floor, ceiling, or similar
surface. It appears absolutely real when viewed, but physical objects
can pass through it without difficulty. When the spell is used to hide
pits, traps, or normal doors, any detection abilities that do not
require sight work normally. Touch or a probing search reveals the
true nature of the surface, though such measures do not cause the
illusion to disappear. Although the caster can see through his
illusory wall, other creatures cannot, even if they succeed at their
Will save (but they do learn that it is not real).

I'm not sure that something like a rough rockface counts as a "wall, floor, ceiling, or similar surface".
Hallucinatory Terrain/Mirage Arcana
If illusory wall doesn't work, it seems like mirage arcana should, since it can conceal both structures and natural terrain. I'm unclear on whether hallucinatory terrain by itself would work, since its description reads:

Hallucinatory Terrain
School illusion (glamer); Level bard 4, sorcerer/wizard 4; Elemental
School wood 4
CASTING
Casting Time 10 minutes Components V, S, M (a stone, a twig, and a
green leaf)
EFFECT
Range long (400 ft. + 40 ft./level) Area one 30-ft. cube/level (S)
Duration 2 hours/level (D) Saving Throw Will disbelief (if interacted
with); Spell Resistance no
DESCRIPTION
You make natural terrain look, sound, and smell like some other sort
of natural terrain. Structures, equipment, and creatures within the
area are not hidden or changed in appearance.

From this description, it seems clear that hallucinatory terrain could make a forest look like a jungle, or perhaps a snowy forest. However, since it doesn't have the same text that illusory wall does about concealing traps, it's not clear to me if that's something hallucinatory terrain can actually do.

I'm not trying to answer in comments, but I have to wonder why permanent image isn't an option.

Why do you feel that Illusory Wall can't replicate the stone around the cave entrance? If you're inside a cave, is the stone around you not the wall, floor, or ceiling? It seems that the description of the spell indicates it's supposed to be used for this very purpose.


An ideal answer would cite a published adventure in which one of these spells was used to accomplish something similar.

Permanent Image was used for this purpose in Adventure Path #88, Valley of the Brain Collectors. A hideout entrance in a cliff face is concealed behind what appears to be a mass of vines, with the spell having been obtained from a scroll.

Both Illusory Wall and Permanent Image should work
I don’t have modules to quote for you, but it is also not clear to me why those would be needed here. First, Illusory Wall says

This spell creates the illusion of a wall, floor, ceiling, or similar surface.

This does not say it must be a fabricated or worked wall. Any kind of wall, or similar surface, including a natural rock wall should work. It has the added benefit of only being fourth spell level, so it is probably your best option.
As pointed out by @HeyICanChan in the comments, alternatively you could use a Permanent Image.  It also would work, but it's level 6, so not as easily accessible.
Lastly: if this is for an NPC, you do not need to justify the illusion with a book spell. They could have researched their own unique magic for this.
